# how to write multiline string with same indentation in yaml

Tags: yaml

I want to write multiline string, with two lines, which will be equally indentated by 8 spaces. Ideally without need to have those 8 spaces in input, but I'm willing to do that. Anything so that I can have the result. I think i tried whole documentation. `'`, `|` `>` `>-`, `>+`, `>8` ..., ... Adding 8char indentation which isn't in source is optional extra, but so far it seems, that in yaml you can have anything but what you actually typed.

• What is the combination for actual as-is multiline string without any yaml transformations (or say impossible if it's impossible)?

• What is the combination for actual as-is multiline string uniformly shifted to the right by N spaces (or say impossible if it's impossible)?

EDIT: specific example:

```
...

    something: |
      @blahblah            
      @blahblah
...
```

I want field `somehting` to contain 2 line string, each containing `@blahblah`, each prefixed by 8 spaces. In JSON you would write(I know I can do that in yaml, but I'd like to use yaml way to write yaml file):

```
{"something": "        @blahblah\n        @blahblah"}
```

EDIT 2: providing minimal working example.
Java code:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Map;

import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
        InputStream inputStream = Test.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test.yaml");
        Map<String, Object> obj = yaml.load(inputStream);
        String s = (String) obj.get("a");
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

for input:

```
a: |
                                                                @abc
                                                                @def
```

I will get:

```
@abc
@def
```

For input:

```
a: |2
                                                                @abc
                                                                @def
```

I will get:

```
                                                      @abc
                                                      @def
```

How can this be explained??? If positive number after `|` should be for removing extra indentation, I understand it, that without number it will remove all indentation. So if someone want preserved indentation of 4 spaces, it seems he needs to do some math, put indentation of 5 and request to remove 1 using `|1`. No? This is how it should work? What am I missing?

Comment: https://yaml-multiline.info is what I've been using in the past. That said, you mention JSON, which is a subset of YAML. IOW, you can inject pieces of JSON into YAML or even completely use JSON.

Comment: Yes, I know about that site. I figured out using documentation and this site, that I need `|`, probably. But sadly, even site which someone put into action to help with subpar documentation, it does not show how it actually works (see sample in quesion). Or snakeyml is incorrect implementation. This site does not show any difference between `|` and `|9`, while according to @flyx and snakeyaml there is difference.

Comment: Oh, so it's perhaps about a specific implementation, not all of them are the same level of quality. Check their bugtracker, maybe you find something there!

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt can you suggest yaml library I could use for testing, which is known to be valid (for basic syntax)? (for stackoverflow gurus: this is not asking for recommendation of sw, this is attempt to debug what is valid syntax using different providers)

Comment: I have trust in the one from Symfony/PHP, but I honestly wouldn't vouch for any implementation.

Comment: @MartinMucha There's an official [curated source](https://matrix.yaml.info) for the level of conformance of YAML implementations based on the official test suite.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the combination for actual as-is multiline string without any yaml transformations (or say impossible if it's impossible)?

```yaml
--- |2
          droggel
          jug
```

You'll get the string as-is, without the 2 spaces indentation specified by the indentation indicator. Since the indicator must be at least `1` (you can't give `0`), there is no way to do that without indentation. Still, this seems to do what you want.

> What is the combination for actual as-is multiline string uniformly shifted to the right by N spaces (or say impossible if it's impossible)?

YAML is not a programming language and can't do any kind of string transformation, so this is impossible.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Can you explain it? Why 2. What is 2 and what it will do? — ad rtfm: I've read offcial webpage(very cool! in a sarcastic way), other how-tos/documentation, multiple tutorials, and tried to read language specification. I still don't get it / it does not work as described. After 15y in industry, I can without hesitation say, that yaml has one of the worst documentation/specifcation I ever saw. Some undocumented systems writen by reckless junior are more comprehensible than this official documentation.

Comment: ... I didn't found any difference between `|` and `|2`

Comment: @MartinMucha `|` says „look at the first non-empty line after this to discover how much indented the content of this block scalar is“. `|2` says „the following block scalar is 2 spaces more indented than the current level (0 in this case)“, making all spaces beyond the first two be content. If you don't see any difference, you're using a non-conforming YAML implementation.

Comment: It's snakeyaml. Actual behavior cannot be explained by your description of `|` resp. `|2`, IIUC. I've put specific sample into question.

Comment: @MartinMucha That seems to be a case for the SnakeYAML bug tracker then. See the [PyYAML online tool](https://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com) or the [NimYAML online tool](https://nimyaml.org/testing.html) (my work) for how it should work.

Comment: just entered the sample data from edit2 into PyYAML you provided, and it behaves the same as snakeyaml ... Meaning just | removes all indentation.

Comment: @MartinMucha No idea what you're doing, it doesn't for me. We're talking about `|2` here, right? Not giving the indentation indicator *will* rightfully remove all indentation.

Comment: you said:`| says „look at the first non-empty line after this to discover how much indented the content of this block scalar is“. ` — so in my example I (and any editor) would say, that first line is indented by 64 chars. So what was not said, IIUC, that _all_  spaces will be removed, and found indentation is only used to evaluate further lines and their indentation, but 64 chars will be always removed. Or hell, I have really no idea what happens where and why. It's crazy and kinda proof of long known knowledge, that whitespaces should not bear information.

Comment: I got it now, I didn't understand what `|` should really do.

Comment: A language like YAML, which already uses whitespace for information since indentation implies structure, cannot, at the same time, *not* use it to bear information. You are hitting the precise special case for which `|2` was designed, i.e. whitespace at the beginning of a block scalar.